# no Suggestions for word constraints

Tags: marklogic

In my `search:suggest` call I specify a **word** prefix constraint on a element. For some reason I am not getting suggestions for that prefix constraint search:

This code illustrates my problem:

```
let $doc := 
<doc>
  <title>Show me some suggestions!</title>
</doc>

return xdmp:document-insert('so.xml', $doc);

import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
    at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:suggest('title:', 
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="title">
      <word collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en">
        <element name="title" />
      </word>
    </constraint>

    <default-suggestion-source>
      <word-lexicon collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en"/>
    </default-suggestion-source>
  </options>
)
```

This does not result in any suggestions. Only after adding the following `suggestions-source`, I get the expected suggestions:

```
<suggestion-source ref="title">
   <word collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en">
      <element name="title"/>
   </word>
</suggestion-source>
```

This does not seem to be the same with `range` or `collection` constraints, suggestions work out of the box and without a `suggestion-source`.

Is there a reason why suggestions are not shown for `word` constraints, e.g. performance? Is this behaviour documented somewhere?

Using MarkLogic 9.0-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created a word lexicon for a specific JSON property or element, the options should be able to refer to a constraint this way:

```
<default-suggestion-source ref="title"/>
```

or identify the word lexicon inline this way:

```
<default-suggestion-source>
  <word collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en">
    <element name="title" />
  </word>
</default-suggestion-source>
```

The word-lexicon query option specifies the database-wide word lexicon. If the database-wide word lexicon has been enabled for the database, the word-lexicon element should work -- though it is not recommended (unless the database is very small).

For more information, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_89118

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_35361

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks for answering. But this is not exactly what I was looking for. The question is not about the `default-suggestion-source`. Its more like I have an additional constraint "title" beside `default-suggestion-source`. Suggestions for values of the constraint are only shown if I add a `suggestion-source` for it.

Comment: Also, check the String Query 'title:'. I expected this to result in a suggestion list containing "title:Show", "title:me", ... .

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  The intent is that the same query options be reusable for queries, values, and suggestions. A range constraint identifies a range index, which can be used for range queries, facets, and suggestions without any additional information. By contrast, a word constraint could be used for word queries without being backed by a word lexicon. Instead of assuming that all word constraints are backed by a word lexicon instead of being declared for word queries during search, the Search API takes the cautious approach of requiring a declaration for word lexicons.

Comment: Alright, this seems to be a reasonable approach. Thanks for explaining!